# Confused about flagging comments and removal

Tags: support, comments

I flagged two comments earlier as `rude or offensive` - they were, no doubt, they were insults.

The strange thing was these comments were instantly removed and my flags are listed as helpful in my profile. What happened here?

They usually go for review and are dealt with later, correct?

Why did this happen? Was it a coincidence, i.e., they were flagged by someone else and I just happened to flag them a second before they were removed? Or do I have some unlisted privilege allowing me to remove these comments? Or what?

Sorry if I am just missing something obvious, strangely, I have only ever flagged four comments (including these) in all my time here, so I am a bit naive on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this [Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365) (thanks to Ravan for finding the post):

> - If a comment is flagged by three users, it will be auto-soft-deleted. There is no penalty for this. Flagged comments will be surfaced to moderators, so if you have a problem with a comment, flag it.
> - Comments with upvotes [require more flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/reduce-the-threshold-for-comment-deletion-with-flags#comment388189_138168) to be deleted without moderator intervention: 1 more flag per 3 votes above 3 (i.e. number of flags = 3 + score/3).
> - [Comments containing certain keywords need fewer flags than normal to be deleted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment/99853#99853)

Comment: @markkirby Yes exactly. If you look at the previous messages I ran a query to find comments containing the foul word, and all of them got deleted instantly because all of them contained the foul word (maybe some of them also had 4-5 flags already, however a foul word as I understand is enough). Forgot to upvote the question, did that now :)

Comment: This is a great feature, it should help us greatly in keeping this sort of thing in check :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365

Comment: @Ravan Thanks, I added that to the answer.